# React.js Validation

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, validation, reactjs

So I have a form that I am trying to validate in React.js, that goes like this:

```
({
render: function() {
    return React.DOM.form({
      className: 'form-inline',
      onSubmit: this.handleSubmit
    },React.DOM.div({
        className: 'form-group'
     }, React.DOM.input({
          type: 'text',
          className: 'form-control',
          placeholder: 'Name (CN)',
          name: 'team_name',
          value: this.state.team_name,
          onChange: this.handleChange
          })));
    }
});
```

So the name must be in Chinese as prompted in the form above, and for validation I place a method before the post that goes somewhat like

```
if (chinese.test(this.state.team_name)) {
   $.post ...;
} else {
   console.log("Chinese language error");
}
```

where `chinese` is a regex for Chinese characters.

**My question** is upon a failed submission, how can I render an alert or notification with Bootstrap that tells the user that there has been an issue with the form?

I understand that upon pressing submit, the component is re-rendered,so I tried setting a state variable and rendering it as such:

```
if (chinese.test(this.state.team_name)) {
   $.post ...;
} else {
   console.log("Chinese language error");
   this.setState({error: true});
}
```

then...

```
({
render: function() {
    if (this.state.error) {
        React.DOM.div;
    }
    return React.DOM.form({
      className: 'form-inline',
      onSubmit: this.handleSubmit
    },React.DOM.div({
        className: 'form-group'
     }, React.DOM.input({
          type: 'text',
          className: 'form-control',
          placeholder: 'Name (CN)',
          name: 'team_name',
          value: this.state.team_name,
          onChange: this.handleChange
          })));
    }
});
```

And that didn't work. So whats a way using React.js that I could render a notification or an error with Bootstrap HTML through my validation process?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi. If you want to get feedback faster and better try to use just javascript in your questions, not coffee. As far as I know not so many react users use coffeescript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to solve this issue using `localStorage`

After calling the validation using a regex expression, if it didn't pass I would store the error message using `localStorage.setItem('token', 'message)`

Afterwards in the component that rendered the form, I called the message using `localStorage.getItem('token')`

Not the most elegant solution for all situations, but it suits me well as I would clear the `localStorage` each time before setting a new message.